# Magento XML layout

Tags: magento

In the code above, what is the meaning of placing "as="footer_links"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `as="x"` syntax defines a name that templates can use to invoke a block. So, for the following:

```
<block type="text/html" name="outer_block" as="outer_block" template="outer_block.phtml">
    <block type="text/html" name="inner_block" as="inner_block" template="inner_block.phtml">
</block>
```

Inside of `outer_block.phtml`, you can invoke this to render `inner_block.phtml`:

```
<?php print $this->getChildHtml("inner_block"); ?>
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe